# How to generate GUID in salesforce?

Tags: apex, encoding

How do I generate GUID in apex class in salesforce in the following format mentioned(16 bytes or 128 bits)?

BA8D6569-9208-4DBB-9357-A4500838101E

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance